# Convert any non integer or null value to 1

Tags: c#, parsing, extension-methods

I wanted to write extension method which should return 1 if any non integer or null value is supplied. `Int32.TryParse()` parses non integer or null value to `0`.

I have tried

```
 public static int ToInt(this string text)
 {
     int num;
     return int.TryParse(text, out num) ? num : 1;
 }
```

Comment: You need to provide some code on what you've tried so far...

Comment: "`Int32.TryParse()` parses non integer or null value to 0" - no it doesn't - the parse _fails_ and it returns _false_.  You're just seeing the _default_ value of int.

Comment: @DStanley If you set a variable to say "7" and `TryParse` fails your variable will be set to 0.

Comment: @Shoe if the parse fails the value of the output parameter is 0, true, but that's different that "parsing to 0" - if you used `Parse` you would get an exception, not 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just take an object, and test if it's an int:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int i = "124241".ParseToInt();       //124241
        int j = DateTime.Now.ParseToInt();   //-1
     }

     public static int ParseToInt(this object testItem)
     {
        int i;
        return Int32.TryParse(testItem.ToString(), out i) ? i : -1;
     }
}
```

`1` typically means success.  I wouldn't return `1` for a failure.

Comment: I think he wanted 1 instead of -1, but nice answer.

Comment: added a quick note on that

Comment: I am using this returned value to divide other integer variable. hence  I wanted 1 as return value

Comment: certainly return what you see fit, I didn't have a lot of context to go on

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is check if your parse succeeded or not and set the value appropriately.

```
var input = "blah";
int myInt;
bool parseSuccessful = Int32.TryParse(input, out myInt);
if (!parseSuccessful)
{
    myInt = 1;
}
```